# Exchange Powershell C#

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server

Ok so I have no hair left to tear out, so before my fingernails become non existent I thought I better post on here to see if anyone can shed some light.

I have a C# application that randomly works, when I say randomly yesterday it was pulling out data perfectly, today it return absolutely nothing.  My mission is to connect to the exchange management shell and perform a bunch of Get queries and return the results to a list.

Below is my exchange query code.

```
public class EmsSession
    {
        public static List<Lists.ExchangeOverview> ExchOverview()
        {
            List<Lists.ExchangeOverview> data = new List<Lists.ExchangeOverview>();
            PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create();
            PSSnapInException ex;
            powershell.Runspace.RunspaceConfiguration.AddPSSnapIn(Program.SnapInString, out ex);
            if (ex != null) throw ex;
            powershell.AddScript(". $env:ExchangeInstallPath\\bin\\RemoteExchange.ps1");
            powershell.AddScript("Connect-ExchangeServer -auto");
            powershell.Invoke();
            powershell.Streams.ClearStreams();
            powershell.Commands.Clear();
            powershell.AddScript("Get-ExchangeServer | Select Name, Edition, AdminDisplayVersion, ServerRole");
            Collection<PSObject> results = powershell.Invoke();
            data.AddRange(results.Select(obj => new Lists.ExchangeOverview()
            {
                Name = obj.Members["Name"].Value.ToString(),
                Edition = obj.Members["Edition"].Value.ToString(),
                Version = obj.Members["AdminDisplayVersion"].Value.ToString(),
                Role = obj.Members["ServerRole"].Value.ToString()
            }));
            return data;
        }
        public static List<Lists.MailboxCount> MailboxDbCounts()
        {
            List<Lists.MailboxCount> data = new List<Lists.MailboxCount>();
            PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create();
            PSSnapInException ex;
            powershell.Runspace.RunspaceConfiguration.AddPSSnapIn(Program.SnapInString, out ex);
            if (ex != null) throw ex;
            powershell.AddScript(". $env:ExchangeInstallPath\\bin\\RemoteExchange.ps1");
            powershell.AddScript("Connect-ExchangeServer -auto");
            powershell.Invoke();
            powershell.Streams.ClearStreams();
            powershell.Commands.Clear();
            powershell.AddScript("Get-Mailbox | Group-Object -Property:Database | Select-Object name, count");
            Collection<PSObject> results = powershell.Invoke();
            data.AddRange(results.Select(obj => new Lists.MailboxCount()
            {
                Name = obj.Members["name"].Value.ToString(),
                Count = obj.Members["count"].Value.ToString()
            }));
            return data;
        }
        public static List<Lists.DatabaseInformation> DatabaseInformation()
        {
            List<Lists.DatabaseInformation> data = new List<Lists.DatabaseInformation>();
            PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create();
            PSSnapInException ex;
            powershell.Runspace.RunspaceConfiguration.AddPSSnapIn(Program.SnapInString, out ex);
            if (ex != null) throw ex;
            powershell.AddScript(". $env:ExchangeInstallPath\\bin\\RemoteExchange.ps1");
            powershell.AddScript("Connect-ExchangeServer -auto");
            powershell.Invoke();
            powershell.Streams.ClearStreams();
            powershell.Commands.Clear();
            powershell.AddScript("Get-MailboxDatabase -Status | Select Name, EdbFilePath, LogFolderPath");
            Collection<PSObject> results = powershell.Invoke();
            foreach (PSObject obj in results)
            {
                string edbSize = Functions.BytesToString(new System.IO.FileInfo(obj.Members["EdbFilePath"].Value.ToString()).Length, true);
                data.Add(new Lists.DatabaseInformation()
                {
                    Name = obj.Members["Name"].Value.ToString(),
                    DbSize = edbSize,
                    EdbPath = obj.Members["EdbFilePath"].Value.ToString(),
                    LogPath = obj.Members["LogFolderPath"].Value.ToString()
                });
            }
            return data;
        }
        public static ArrayList ExchangeTraffic()
        {
            ArrayList data = new ArrayList();
            StringBuilder stringBuild = new StringBuilder();
            stringBuild.AppendLine("$From = ((Get-Date).AddDays(-30)).Date");
            stringBuild.AppendLine("$To = ((Get-Date).AddDays(-29)).Date");
            stringBuild.AppendLine("[Int64] $intTotalSentInternally = $intTotalSentExternally = 0");
            stringBuild.AppendLine("[Int64] $intTotalRecInternally = $intTotalRecExternally = 0");
            stringBuild.AppendLine("[Int64] $intTotalSentSize = $intTotalSent = 0");
            stringBuild.AppendLine("[Int64] $intTotalRecSize = $intTotalRec = 0");
            stringBuild.AppendLine("[Int64] $intTotalFailed = 0");
            stringBuild.AppendLine("[Int64] $intTotalPoison = $intTotalPoisonHistory = 0");
            stringBuild.AppendLine("[String] $strEmails = $null ");
            stringBuild.AppendLine("Do");
            stringBuild.AppendLine("{");
            stringBuild.AppendLine(@"    $strEmails = ""$($From.ToString(""dd MMM"")),"" ");
            stringBuild.AppendLine("     $intTotalSentInternally = $intTotalSentExternally = 0");
            stringBuild.AppendLine("     $intTotalRecInternally = $intTotalRecExternally = 0");
            stringBuild.AppendLine("     $intTotalSentSize = $intTotalSent = 0");
            stringBuild.AppendLine("     $intTotalRecSize = $intTotalRec = 0");
            stringBuild.AppendLine("     $intTotalFailed = 0");
            stringBuild.AppendLine("     $intTotalPoison = 0");
            stringBuild.AppendLine("    (Get-TransportServer) | Get-MessageTrackingLog -ResultSize Unlimited -Start $From -End $To | ForEach {");
            stringBuild.AppendLine(@"         If ($_.EventId -eq ""RECEIVE"" -and $_.Source -eq ""STOREDRIVER"") {");
            stringBuild.AppendLine("            $intTotalSentSize += $_.TotalBytes");
            stringBuild.AppendLine("            $intTotalSent++");
            stringBuild.AppendLine(@"           If ($_.Recipients -match """ + Program.EmailDomain + @""") {");
            stringBuild.AppendLine("                $intTotalSentInternally++");
            stringBuild.AppendLine("            } Else {");
            stringBuild.AppendLine("                $intTotalSentExternally++");
            stringBuild.AppendLine("            }");
            stringBuild.AppendLine("        }");
            stringBuild.AppendLine(@"        If ($_.EventId -eq ""DELIVER"") {");
            stringBuild.AppendLine("            $intTotalRecSize += $_.TotalBytes");
            stringBuild.AppendLine("            $intTotalRec++");
            stringBuild.AppendLine(@"           If ($_.Sender -match """ + Program.EmailDomain + @""") {");
            stringBuild.AppendLine("                $intTotalRecInternally++");
            stringBuild.AppendLine("            } Else {");
            stringBuild.AppendLine("                $intTotalRecExternally++");
            stringBuild.AppendLine("            }");
            stringBuild.AppendLine("        }");
            stringBuild.AppendLine(@"        If ($_.EventId -eq ""FAIL"") {");
            stringBuild.AppendLine("            $intTotalFailed++");
            stringBuild.AppendLine("        }");
            stringBuild.AppendLine(@"        If ($_.EventId -eq ""POISONMESSAGE"") {");
            stringBuild.AppendLine("            $intTotalPoison++");
            stringBuild.AppendLine("        }");
            stringBuild.AppendLine("    }");
            stringBuild.AppendLine("    $intTotalPoison = $intTotalPoison - $intTotalPoisonHistory");
            stringBuild.AppendLine("    $intTotalPoisonHistory = $intTotalPoison");
            stringBuild.AppendLine(@"    $strEmails += ""$intTotalSent,$intTotalSentInternally,$intTotalSentExternally,$intTotalSentSize,$intTotalRec,$intTotalRecInternally,$intTotalRecExternally,$intTotalRecSize,$intTotalFailed,$intTotalPoison""");
            stringBuild.AppendLine("    $strEmails");
            stringBuild.AppendLine("    $From = $From.AddDays(1)");
            stringBuild.AppendLine("    $To = $From.AddDays(1)");
            stringBuild.AppendLine("}");
            stringBuild.AppendLine("While ($To -lt (Get-Date))");
            PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create();
            PSSnapInException ex;
            powershell.Runspace.RunspaceConfiguration.AddPSSnapIn(Program.SnapInString, out ex);
            if (ex != null) throw ex;
            powershell.AddScript(". $env:ExchangeInstallPath\\bin\\RemoteExchange.ps1");
            powershell.AddScript("Connect-ExchangeServer -auto");
            powershell.Invoke();
            powershell.Streams.ClearStreams();
            powershell.Commands.Clear();
            powershell.AddScript(stringBuild.ToString());
            Collection<PSObject> results = powershell.Invoke();
            foreach (PSObject obj in results)
            {
                data.Add(obj.ToString());
            }
            return data;
        }
        public static List<Lists.FailedEmails> FailedEmails()
        {
            List<Lists.FailedEmails> data = new List<Lists.FailedEmails>();
            StringBuilder strBuild = new StringBuilder();
            strBuild.AppendLine(@"[Array]$List_FailedEmailsBySender = Get-TransportServer | Get-MessageTrackingLog -ResultSize 'Unlimited' -EventID FAIL -Start ((Get-Date).AddDays(-30)).Date | Sort-Object -Property Sender | Group-Object -Property Sender");
            strBuild.AppendLine(@"$ProcessedList = New-Object -TypeName System.Collections.ArrayList");
            strBuild.AppendLine(@"foreach ($Sender in $List_FailedEmailsBySender) {");
            strBuild.AppendLine(@"    $Sender.Group | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Recipients | Sort-Object | Group-Object | ForEach-Object {");
            strBuild.AppendLine(@"        [VOID]$ProcessedList.Add((New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{");
            strBuild.AppendLine(@"            Sender = $Sender.Name");
            strBuild.AppendLine(@"            Recipient = $_.Name");
            strBuild.AppendLine(@"            FailedCount = $_.Count");
            strBuild.AppendLine(@"        }))");
            strBuild.AppendLine(@"    }");
            strBuild.AppendLine(@"}");
            strBuild.AppendLine(@"[Array]$Top20 = $ProcessedList | Sort-Object -Property FailedCount -Descending | Select-Object -First 20 | Select-Object -Property Sender,Recipient,FailedCount");
            strBuild.AppendLine(@"$Top20");
            PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create();
            PSSnapInException ex;
            powershell.Runspace.RunspaceConfiguration.AddPSSnapIn(Program.SnapInString, out ex);
            if (ex != null) throw ex;
            powershell.AddScript(". $env:ExchangeInstallPath\\bin\\RemoteExchange.ps1");
            powershell.AddScript("Connect-ExchangeServer -auto");
            powershell.Invoke();
            powershell.Streams.ClearStreams();
            powershell.Commands.Clear();
            powershell.AddScript(strBuild.ToString());
            Collection<PSObject> results = powershell.Invoke();
            data.AddRange(results.Select(obj => new Lists.FailedEmails()
            {
                Sender = obj.Members["Sender"].Value.ToString(),
                Recipient = obj.Members["Recipient"].Value.ToString(),
                Count = obj.Members["FailedCount"].Value.ToString()
            }));
            return data;
        }
        public static List<Lists.TopMailboxes> TopMailboxes()
        {
            List<Lists.TopMailboxes> data = new List<Lists.TopMailboxes>();
            PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create();
            PSSnapInException ex;
            powershell.Runspace.RunspaceConfiguration.AddPSSnapIn(Program.SnapInString, out ex);
            if (ex != null) throw ex;
            powershell.AddScript(". $env:ExchangeInstallPath\\bin\\RemoteExchange.ps1");
            powershell.AddScript("Connect-ExchangeServer -auto");
            powershell.Invoke();
            powershell.Streams.ClearStreams();
            powershell.Commands.Clear();
            powershell.AddScript("Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | Get-MailboxStatistics | Sort-Object TotalItemSize -Descending | Select-Object DisplayName,@{name='TotalItemSize';expression={[math]::Round((($_.TotalItemSize.Value.ToString()).Split('(')[1].Split(' ')[0].Replace(',','')/1GB),2)}} -First 20");
            Collection<PSObject> results = powershell.Invoke();
            data.AddRange(results.Select(obj => new Lists.TopMailboxes()
            {
                MailboxName = obj.Members["DisplayName"].Value.ToString(),
                Size = obj.Members["TotalItemSize"].Value.ToString()
            }));
            return data;
        }
    }
}
```

I am not getting any errors from the server it is run on, I am just getting completely blank data.

I can confirm that the variable Program.SnapInString returns the correct exchange snap in to use (which is Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Powershell.E2010)

Maybe tomorrow it will work again!!

Any ideas would be amazing.

---One more thing to add this runs as the system account (if that would make any difference, not as a logged on user)

Comment: why not to use just powershell script , without c# wrapper or if you are using C# , then use Exchange API , it is pretty well documented(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn567668(v=exchg.150).aspx).

Comment: The reason I am not using just a powershell script is that once this data is captured the C# program will generate a PDF report based on the data and also imports that data into a SQL database

Comment: If I can get this to work reliably and if anyone is interested I am happy to publish the full code as the report is pretty cool (in my humble opinion)

Comment: you know you can use any .net stuff in powershell right? just do all the stuff in powershell, since you are using powershell api for ES, after that you'll have data structure that you will pass to some module  which might be you c# module rendering PDF

Comment: NO if I am honest I did not know that, my knowledge of powershell is limited, I get by.

Comment: powershell has full access to all .net classes, it is just one more language on clr ( like c#/vb/f#).  I just think you will make your life easier and testing easier if you clearly separate getting report data and generating pdf from data and in your case first part is a lot easier with plain powershell. So do that. Once you have all the data you can serialize it to file just to know what you've got, and then pass that to your c# program to generate report from your (xml) file.

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize it:

```
public class EmsSession
    {
    static PSCredential cred = (PSCredential)null;
    static WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri("http://exchangeserver01.my.domain/powershell?serializationLevel=Full"), 
                                                                         "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange", cred);

    public static string GetPropertyValue(this PSObject psObject, string propertyName)
    {
        string ret = string.Empty;
        if (psObject.Properties[propertyName].Value != null)
            ret = psObject.Properties[propertyName].Value.ToString();

        return ret;
    }
    public static List<Lists.ExchangeOverview> ExchOverview()
    {
        var data = new List<Lists.ExchangeOverview>();          
        connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Kerberos;
        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo)
        PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create()

        Command cmd1 = new Command("Get-ExchangeServer");
        powershell.Commands.Commands.Add(cmd1);
        runspace.Open();
        powershell.Runspace = runspace;
        Collection<PSObject> psResults = powershell.Invoke();

        foreach (PSObject psResult in psResults)
        {
            data.AddRange(results.Select(obj => new Lists.ExchangeOverview()
                    {
                        Name = psResult.GetPropertyValue("Name"),
                        Edition = psResult.GetPropertyValue("ItemCount"),
                        Version = psResult.GetPropertyValue("AdminDisplayVersion"),
                        Role = psResult.GetPropertyValue("ServerRole"),
                    }));                
        }

        foreach (ErrorRecord psError in powershell.Streams.Error)
        {
            errors.Add(
                new emsErrorRecord
                {
                    Command = psError.CategoryInfo.Activity,
                    Reason = psError.CategoryInfo.Reason,
                    Message = psError.Exception.Message
                });
        }

        foreach (WarningRecord psWarning in powershell.Streams.Warning)
        {
            warnings.Add(
                new emsWarningRecord
                {
                    Command = psWarning.InvocationInfo.MyCommand.Name,
                    Message = psWarning.Message
                });
        }

        runspace.Dispose();
        runspace = null;

        powershell.Dispose();
        powershell = null;
        return data;
    }

    public static List<Lists.MailboxCount> MailboxDbCounts()
    {
        var data = new List<Lists.MailboxCount>();  
        var databases = DatabaseInformation();
        connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Kerberos;
        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo)
        PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create()

        Command cmd1 = new Command("Get-Mailbox");
        powershell.Commands.Commands.Add(cmd1);
        runspace.Open();
        powershell.Runspace = runspace;
        Collection<PSObject> psResults = powershell.Invoke();

        foreach (PSObject psResult in psResults)
        {
            foreach(Lists.DatabaseInformation database in databases)
            {
                int counter = 0;
                if(database.Name == psResult.GetPropertyValue("Name"))
                {
                    counter++;
                }
                data.Add(new Lists.MailboxCount()
                {
                    Name = obj.Members["name"].Value.ToString(),
                    Count = counter.ToString()
                }));
            }           
        }

        foreach (ErrorRecord psError in powershell.Streams.Error)
        {
            errors.Add(
                new emsErrorRecord
                {
                    Command = psError.CategoryInfo.Activity,
                    Reason = psError.CategoryInfo.Reason,
                    Message = psError.Exception.Message
                });
        }

        foreach (WarningRecord psWarning in powershell.Streams.Warning)
        {
            warnings.Add(
                new emsWarningRecord
                {
                    Command = psWarning.InvocationInfo.MyCommand.Name,
                    Message = psWarning.Message
                });
        }

        runspace.Dispose();
        runspace = null;

        powershell.Dispose();
        powershell = null;
    }           

    public static List<Lists.DatabaseInformation> DatabaseInformation()
    {
        var data = new List<Lists.DatabaseInformation>();       
        connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Kerberos;
        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo)
        PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create()

        Command cmd1 = new Command("Get-MailboxDatabase");
        powershell.Commands.Commands.Add(cmd1);
        runspace.Open();
        powershell.Runspace = runspace;
        Collection<PSObject> psResults = powershell.Invoke();

        foreach (PSObject psResult in psResults)
        {
            string edbSize = Functions.BytesToString(new System.IO.FileInfo(obj.Members["EdbFilePath"].Value.ToString()).Length, true);
            data.AddRange(results.Select(obj => new Lists.MailboxCount()
                    {
                        Name = psResult.GetPropertyValue("Name"),
                        DbSize = edbSize,
                        EdbPath = psResult.GetPropertyValue("EdbFilePath"),
                        LogPath = psResult.GetPropertyValue("LogFolderPath")
                    }));                
        }

        foreach (ErrorRecord psError in powershell.Streams.Error)
        {
            errors.Add(
                new emsErrorRecord
                {
                    Command = psError.CategoryInfo.Activity,
                    Reason = psError.CategoryInfo.Reason,
                    Message = psError.Exception.Message
                });
        }

        foreach (WarningRecord psWarning in powershell.Streams.Warning)
        {
            warnings.Add(
                new emsWarningRecord
                {
                    Command = psWarning.InvocationInfo.MyCommand.Name,
                    Message = psWarning.Message
                });
        }

        runspace.Dispose();
        runspace = null;

        powershell.Dispose();
        powershell = null;
    }
}
```